# Coldfusion, ORM-Hibernate, one-to-one property relationship one same table

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion

A previous developer created a table with properties that refer to the id field in the same table so I have a need to create a one-to-one relationship with with two properties in the same table.  How is this done?

Here's what I have...

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="Users">

    <cfproperty name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="increment" >

    <cfproperty name="inserted_by" fieldType="one-to-one" cfc="Users" fkcolumn="id" >

</cfcomponent>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: I get an error message...

Repeated column in mapping for entity: Users column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")